# Ajax call not working properly

Tags: ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Login.aspx/LoginUser",
                data: "{'LoginObject':" + JSON.stringify(LoginObject) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d == "Success") {
                        location.href = "Share.aspx";
                    }
                    else if(data.d == "Failure")
                    {
                        $("#lblStatus").html("Username or Password supplied is invalid. Please try again.");
                    }
                },
            });
```

When data.d is Failure then the condition statement executes but when data.d is Success then the page doesnt jump to Share.aspx. What is the problem in the code?

Comment: Is there an extra space in "Success" ? Try trimming it.

Comment: Put a log statement in that `if` block, is it being executed?

Comment: Try adding an error handler callback, inspect the parameters of the callback for any error messages. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Open developer tools and look for any error messages in the console. Look at the network tab of dev tools and look at the html req / resp. Looks at the http status code of the response. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Put a log statement before that `if` block then and let us know what shows up.

Comment: responseText:{\"Message\":\"Authentication failed.\",\"StackTrace\":null,\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\"}" String
status 401
statusText Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a problem with the request format you are sending. Look at the network tab of dev tools and look at the html req / resp. Look at the format of the request body (LoginObject) and compare that to what your server technology documentation states should be the appropriate request format.

There is no need to 'stringify' your LoginObject for the `data` parameter. The `data` parameter expects an object literal as value.

> data Type: PlainObject or String Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "Login.aspx/LoginUser",
 data: {
  LoginObject:LoginObject
 },
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
  console.dir(data);
  if (data.d == "Success") {
   location.href = "Share.aspx";
  } else if(data.d == "Failure") {
   $("#lblStatus").html("Username or Password supplied is invalid. Please try again.");
  }
 },
});
```

Comment: Nope. After adding the above code now both success and failure dont work!! With my code, I Failure conditional statement works, but not the Success conditional statement

Comment: The snippet above was only to show that the data parameter should not be a JSON string. Did you look at the format of the request body (LoginObject) and compare that to what your server technology documentation states should be the appropriate request format? What did you find? If the request is formatted correctly, it would be time to move on to troubleshooting server-side.

Comment: Server side returns a string as Success or Failure.
It works for Failure but not for Success

Comment: You clearly are looking for a copy/paste answer and don't want to do any research or troubleshooting on your own.

Comment: I have tried almost everything and my head is spinning. I cant figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: Did you look at the format of the request body (LoginObject) and compare that to what your server technology documentation states should be the appropriate request format? Try logging the response in the success callback (updated code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Login.aspx/LoginUser",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({
         id: ce
     }),
     success: function(data) {
         if (data.d == "Success") {
             location.href = "Share.aspx";
         } else if (data.d == "Failure") {
             $("#lblStatus").html("Username or Password supplied is invalid. Please try again.");
         }
     },
     error: function() {
         alert("Oh no:");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem!!! One of my web service was calling FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true). This was clearly as to why I was getting Authentication failed!!! Upon removing it the ajax call ran properly. :) Cheers...